# Using element queries in general.php config file

Tags: config

Can i use element queries in `general.php` file? I wanted to set `loginPath` based on entry query, like this:

```
'loginPath' => Craft::$app->entries->section('login')->one()->url ?? false,
```

Hovewer, i get error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Craft' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\config\general.php on line 40
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this at the top of `config/general.php` file:

```
use craft\elements\Entry;
```

And change your `loginPath` value to:

```
'loginPath' => function() {
   return Entry::find()->section('login')->one()->url ?? null;
},
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar - i pasted "use Craft", but it didnt helped. I wonder why.

Comment: Please confirm and/or upvote for this answer it you think this is a right and viable solution :)